# Error connecting to SQL Server 2012 using NodeJS and mssql package

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I'm using the mssql package for node in a MacOs Monterey:

```
import mssql from "mssql"

connect = async () => {
    try {
      var cfg = {
        server: "10.0.0.180",
        authentication: {
          type: "default",
          options: {
            userName: "username",
            password: "password",
          },
        },
        options: {
          encrypt: true,
          enableArithAbort: true,
          integratedSecurity: true,
          trustServerCertificate: true,
          rowCollectionOnDone: true,
          database: "db",
          cryptoCredentialsDetails: {
            // Required for SQL Server 2012 connection,
            // as node 18 uses a newer TLS protocol
            minVersion: "TLSv1",
          },
        },
      };

      let conn = await mssql.connect(cfg);

      return conn;
    } catch (error) {
      return null;
    }

    return false;
  };
```

Working with node v18.13.0 I'm getting the following error:

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 10.0.0.180:1433 - 0036761901000000:error:0A000102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/statem/statem_lib.c:1986:

My project config:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "mssql": "^9.0.1",
    "nconf": "^0.12.0",
    "qs": "^6.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  }
```

I'm stuck on that as I cannot connect to the database. What might be causing this?

Comment: You are using Node.js 18? TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 are considered to be insecure protocols and have been disabled by default since [Node.js 12](https://nodejs.org/tr/blog/uncategorized/10-lts-to-12-lts/).

Comment: I guess an interesting question is... TLS 1.2 has been supported with service packs and hotfixes since SQL Server 2008 SP3, so why is your SQL Server 2012 instance not supporting TLS 1.2 connectivity? Ref: [KB3135244 - TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe).

Comment: I guess this is not related to SQL Server 2012, but to `node` or  `mssql`. I've used that configuration in the same server/same client laptop in another project - I was using node 19 and worked fine. For that new project I had to downgrade to node 18 as I needed the `qs` package, unavailable to nodejs. From that moment on none of the projects are connecting to SQL any more. I've tried to go back to node 19 and no success....

Comment: Have updated SQL Server 2012 to Service Pack 4, but the problem still persists...